# Pascal string to pointer

Tags: string, pointers, pascal

I'm trying to make log with in sdl and i need to write time.
Text must be pointer.

```
date //pointer
:=
DateTimeToStr(Now);// AnsiString
```

Here date is pointer and DateTimeToStr(Now) returns AnsiString and compiler stops there.
How to fix it?

Comment: It helps if you provide the declaration of the function you'll be calling, so we can see the actual data types that are expected. I doubt that the SDL code is simply asking for a parameter of type `pointer`. It's more likely defined as `char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using either Delphi or FreePascal. Your current code will give you an `Incompatible Types` error. You need to assign the result of `DateTimeToStr(Now)` to a string and assign your pointer to the address of that string. Here is an example.

```
procedure ShowDateTime;
var
  date: ^AnsiString;
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  str := DateTimeToStr(Now);
  date := @str;
  Writeln(date^);
end;
```

Read how to use pointers in [Delphi](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Pointers) or [FreePascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Pointers).

Comment: Shouldn't they just be using PChar/PWideChar?

Comment: This is wrong, unless you're using a 1980's version of Pascal. Any modern version (meaning later than Turbo Pascal) would use PChar for this instead. (And since you've referred the poster to *using pointers in Delphi or FreePascal*, I guess we can presume that 1980's Pascal is off the table.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `PChar`, which is `pointer to Char`.

```
var
  str: AnsiString;
  pDateStr: PChar;
...
  str := DateTimeToStr(Now);
  pDateStr := PChar(str);
  // Do whatever you want with the PChar pDateStr
```